# An entry with multiple keys in the related field: is Biblatex expected to split multiple related entries into multiple paragraphs?

Tags: biblatex

I want to cite an essay that was originally published in 2 parts, `Part1` and `Part2`, in consecutive years, but published again later as a single `Reprint` essay in a `Collection` of my author's essays.

According to pages 69--70 from the Biblatex (v 3.0) documentation, the `related` field supports multiple keys, so that `related={Part1,Part2}` is valid.

However, the bibliography reference I get from citing `Reprint` looks odd, in that while `Part1` appears where it should be, `Part2` is typeset as a **new paragraph** beginning with a **dangling period**.

[image]

Is this expected behavior? Is Biblatex expected to split multiple related entries into multiple paragraphs?

What is the proper way of adding such a `Reprint` to my database?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{kristeller.bib}

@article           {Part1,
 author=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {The modern system of the arts (I)},
 journal=          {Journal of the History of Ideas},
 volume=           {12},
 number=           {4},
 pages=            {496--527},
 relatedtype=      {reprintas},
 related=          {Reprint},
 xref=             {Part2},
 year=             {1951}}

@article           {Part2,
 author=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {The modern system of the arts (II)},
 journal=          {Journal of the History of Ideas},
 volume=           {13},
 number=           {1},
 pages=            {17-46},
 relatedtype=      {reprintas},
 related=          {Reprint},
 xref=             {Part1},
 year=             {1952}}

@incollection      {Reprint,
 author=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {The modern system of the arts},
 pages=            {163-227},
 relatedtype=      {reprintof},
 related=          {Part1,Part2},
 crossref=         {Collection},
 year=             {1965}}

@collection        {Collection,
 editor=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {Renaissance thought and the arts},
 location=         {Princeton, NJ},
 publisher=        {Princeton University Press},
 year=             {1965}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[
  backend=biber,
  style=authortitle,
]
{biblatex}

\renewcommand\subtitlepunct{\addcolon\addspace}
\addbibresource{kristeller.bib}    

\begin{document}

\fullcite{Reprint}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `xref`? That doesn't seem necessary or especially desirable. (I'm not saying it is the cause of the problem. I doubt that.)

Comment: It's useful if you have a script to extract an entry together with any other entries that are somehow related to it. And `Part1` and `Part2` are clearly related as parts of a whole, although Biblatex has no `relatedtype` value to make room for that.

Comment: It seems an abuse of `xref`, though. Why not make up a new field to avoid potential problems?

Comment: Sure. For my education, what kind of potential problems do you have in mind?  I thought `xref` would not let one entry meddle with another entry's data.

Comment: I meant more that if you later wanted to use `xref` in entries for its usual purpose, you might get unwanted side-effects. If you are using it just for use by an external script, the script can just as well use an arbitrary field you invent just for that purpose. It just seemed odd to use `xref` as well as the `related` stuff. But maybe you do want Biblatex to act on the `xref` in certain circumstances e.g. so that `Reprint` gets added even if you tell Biblatex to ignore `related` settings.

Comment: I see. Maybe `otherparts` will do.  It would be great if Biblatex had a field for this kind of relationship natively, though, as works published in parts do exist. It would have to be something other than a new `relatedtype` value, a field that merely established a relationship between entries with no further consequences for what and how entries are added to the bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to redefine the delimiter used between related entries when the data is typeset as, by default, it is a line break. The macro provided by Biblatex for this is `\relateddelim` (page 223 of the current manual). Here, I redefine it to be a comma followed by a space:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article           {Part1,
 author=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {The modern system of the arts (I)},
 journal=          {Journal of the History of Ideas},
 volume=           {12},
 number=           {4},
 pages=            {496--527},
 relatedtype=      {reprintas},
 related=          {Reprint},
 year=             {1951}}

@article           {Part2,
 author=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {The modern system of the arts (II)},
 journal=          {Journal of the History of Ideas},
 volume=           {13},
 number=           {1},
 pages=            {17-46},
 relatedtype=      {reprintas},
 related=          {Reprint},
 year=             {1952}}

@incollection      {Reprint,
 author=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {The modern system of the arts},
 pages=            {163-227},
 relatedtype=      {reprintof},
 related=          {Part1,Part2},
 crossref=         {Collection},
 year=             {1965}}

@collection        {Collection,
 editor=           {Kristeller, Paul Oskar},
 title=            {Renaissance thought and the arts},
 location=         {Princeton, NJ},
 publisher=        {Princeton University Press},
 year=             {1965}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[
  backend=biber,
  style=authortitle,
]
{biblatex}
\renewcommand*\relateddelim{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand\subtitlepunct{\addcolon\addspace}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{Reprint}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: redefining related delimiters]

Comment: What I can't work out is why the default delimiter would be a line break, especially since it gives such odd results.