# Multiple related entries split into multiple paragraphs using angew-chem

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chem

This question is related to "[An entry with multiple keys in the related field: is Biblatex expected to split multiple related entries into multiple paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262574/)". However, I am using the `biblatex-chem` style `chem-angew`, which has different output.

I am trying to add multiple related entries to a reference. They are related, as the second two publications are corrections of the first two. As in the aforementioned question, the first related entry is placed delimited by a semicolon as it should be.

**The Problem:** All subsequent entries are delimited only by a comma.

Using the solution of `\renewcommand*\relateddelim{}` does remove printing on a new line, but it doesn't matter if I have `\addcolon`, `\addsemicolon` or anything like that before `\addspace`.

My MWE (bibliography data stripped of unnecessary information for this MWE):

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Buntin.2008.ange,
  author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
  year = {2008},
  pages = {4671--4676},
  pagination = {page},
  volume = {120},
  journal = {Angew. Chem.},
  related = {Buntin.2008.anie,Buntin.2009.ange,Buntin.2009.anie},
  relatedtype = {translatedas}
}

@article{Buntin.2008.anie,
  author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
  year = {2008},
  pages = {4595--4599},
  pagination = {page},
  volume = {47},
  journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
}

@article{Buntin.2009.ange,
  author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
  year = {2009},
  pages = {9957},
  pagination = {page},
  volume = {121},
  journal = {Angew. Chem.},
}

@article{Buntin.2009.anie,
  author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
  year = {2009},
  pages = {9773},
  pagination = {page},
  volume = {48},
  journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*\relateddelim{\addsemicolon\addspace}

\begin{document}
  Cited.\autocite{Buntin.2008.ange}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Image of produced output.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard styles used to have a structurally similar problem that was fixed in version 3.11 (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/704/files). The `\relateddelim`s should be printed with `\printunit` since the next `\print...` command might print nothing.

The same fix for `chem-angew`:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Buntin.2008.ange,
        author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
        year = {2008},
        pages = {4671--4676},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {120},
        journal = {Angew. Chem.},
        related = {Buntin.2008.anie,Buntin.2009.ange,Buntin.2009.anie},
        relatedtype = {translatedas}
    }

    @article{Buntin.2008.anie,
        author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
        year = {2008},
        pages = {4595--4599},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {47},
        journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
    }

    @article{Buntin.2009.ange,
        author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
        year = {2009},
        pages = {9957},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {121},
        journal = {Angew. Chem.},
    }

    @article{Buntin.2009.anie,
        author = {Buntin, Kathrin},
        year = {2009},
        pages = {9773},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {48},
        journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*\relateddelim{\addsemicolon\addspace}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{related}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    not test {\iftoggle{bbx:related}}
    or
    test {\iffieldundef{related}}
  }
    {}
    {%
     \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
     \setcounter{bbx:relatedcount}{0}%
     \setcounter{bbx:relatedtotal}{0}%
     \def\do##1{\stepcounter{bbx:relatedtotal}}%
     \docsvfield{related}%
     \def\do{%
       \stepcounter{bbx:relatedcount}%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{bbx:relatedcount}}{1}
         {\printunit{\relateddelim}}
         {}}%
     \ifbibmacroundef{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}
       {\appto{\do}{\usebibmacro{related:default}}}
       {\appto{\do}{\usebibmacro*{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}}}%
     \iffieldformatundef{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}
       {\def\bbx@tempa{related}}
       {\def\bbx@tempa{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}}%
     \printtext[\bbx@tempa]{%
       \iffieldundef{relatedstring}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{bbx:relatedtotal}}{1}}
            and
            test {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{relatedtype}s}}
          }
            {\printtext{\bibstring{\thefield{relatedtype}s}\relatedpunct}}
            {\iffieldbibstring{relatedtype}
               {\printtext{\bibstring{\thefield{relatedtype}}\relatedpunct}}
               {}}}
         {\iffieldbibstring{relatedstring}
            {\printtext{\bibstring{\thefield{relatedstring}}\relatedpunct}}
            {\printtext{\printfield{relatedstring}\relatedpunct}}}%
       \docsvfield{related}}}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
    Cited.\autocite{Buntin.2008.ange}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]